# Is it possible to choose a version of TOR that works with a site?

Tags: update

Question from a newbie.

Here's what's going on. I updated to the latest version of TOR, and then at the site I most visit, they would not even recognize the latest version as a "Firefox". They asked me to log in again from the previous device I used (which was of course, the same device, but with an earlier version of TOR).

Other issues I faced associated with the latest version:

(1) the network I choose, (after left clicking the blue "choose a new Tor network" button once) changes the network not once but 2 times after I press the button, making it difficult to choose a preferred exit node.

(2) Like I mentioned before, the site does not even recognize latest TOR as a "firefox", making it difficult to log in. Asks security questions a couple of times, then didn't allow me in.Never happened with earlier versions.

(3) Some of the dialogues like whether I want to block HTTP canvas cookies never show up!

What I did: dumped the latest version of TOR, went back to the TOR 4.5.1 (luckily I had that exe installer file still on the device) and though the site allowed me in, many functionalities at the site are gone. Difficult to navigate.

Question(s): Can I choose to update to a somewhat higher version of TOR, without upgrading to the latest version?

Can I pick and choose which version I want? Is there any place where I can get more recent (but not the latest) installer exe files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the latest version is rubbish and dangerous, many bugs and dosen't work half the time + noscript 10 is a nightmare.
You can put any version you want on and run it. The last good version is v7.5.6 you can download it from here.-
https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/7.5.6/
Be sure to go to settings and select "Never check for updates" or "Check for updates, but let me choose whether to install them"
 or it will update straight away to v8 so do it quick.
Click top right menu button --> Prefrences ---> Advanced---> update (tab)

Remember you are open to security issues by not having the latest version, but then again if you use v8 this is also true because you can't set noscript to block scripts globally. + lots of websites don't work with v8 so it is useless anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Newbie question: the files in that index are named so that I can't make out which one to download as none of them end with .exe. Which one do I need for Windows 64 bit?

Comment: Is it this file: TorBrowser-7.5.6-osx64_en-US.dmg? Never heard of that extension, so just checking. I need Windows 64 bit download. Thanks.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the page and get https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/7.5.6/torbrowser-install-7.5.6_en-US.exe - AFAIK, they didn't start making 64bit versions until 8.0 (which is the crap you don't want).